# Manually Installing a separate instance of shared libraries without touching/damaging already existing ones

Tags: installation, shared-libraries

I am going to analyze some ".so" shared libraries in Ubuntu. To do that, I have to install or re-install these libraries manually, using their corresponding packages. My question is that what is the safest way to do it? Can I build them in a way that the system's already installed libraries are not touched/damaged?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I build them in a way that the system's already installed libraries are not touched/damaged?

Yes: for every sane package, `make` builds the libraries, and only `make install` installs them. So don't do `make install` and your system libraries will not be touched.

P.S. You should not be running as `root`, and if you are not, then `make install` will fail anyway, because unprivileged users can't overwrite system libraries.